# ¿Cómo puedo crear una consulta anidada o subconsulta que obtenga valores nulos o no existentes?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, subconsultas

tengo un ejercicio que me pide que  'Muestre la matrícula y año de ITV de los vehículos que pertenezcan a la categoría “coche” y que no se hayan reservado nunca'

las tablas que tengo serian las siguientes :

```
-vehiculos:
  IdVehiculo(PRI),
  fk_IdMarca,
  fk_IdCategoria,
  fk_IdModelo,
  N_matricula, 
  Año_ITV 
-reservas:
  IdReserva(PRI), 
  IdCliente_realiza_reserva, 
  IdVehiculo_reservado,
  Hora_fin_alquiler, 
  Hora_inicio_alquiler,
  Fecha_alquiler,
  Trayecto
-categoria:
  IdCategoria,
  Nombre
```

se hacerlo con otra clase de sentencia que no es subconsulta pero me pide que lo haga con subconsulta ,lo he intentado así pero algo no funciona y ya la cambie de diferentes formas .
Pienso que la sentencia con la que intento sacar las reservas no producidas no esta bien hecha y no se como crearla bien

este fue el ultimo intento que hice:

```
SELECT
   v.N_Matricula AS 'Matricula',
   v.Año_ITV AS 'Año de ITV'
FROM 
    vehiculos v 
WHERE 
  (v.fk_IdCategoria=(
    SELECT categoria.IdCategoria
    FROM categoria
    WHERE categoria.Nombre='deportivo')
  ) AND 
  (v.IdVehiculo IN(
    SELECT reservas.IdVehiculo_reservado
    FROM reservas
    WHERE reservas.IdReserva IS NULL)
  )
```

Asi la consulta me enseña la tabla pero vacía , en cambio si me muestra las reservas producidas  de esa categoria  cambiando IS NULL  por  IS NOT NULL

```
SELECT
   v.N_Matricula  AS 'Matricula',v.Año_ITV AS 'Año de ITV'
FROM 
    vehiculos v 
WHERE 
  (v.fk_IdCategoria=(
    SELECT categoria.IdCategoria
    FROM categoria
    WHERE categoria.Nombre='deportivo')
  ) AND 
  (v.IdVehiculo IN(
    SELECT reservas.IdVehiculo_reservado
    FROM reservas
    WHERE reservas.IdReserva IS NOT NULL)
  )
```

Comment: Suena a `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: `IdReserva(PRI),` si es clave primaria no debería haber registro con `idReserva = null` proba dar vuelta la comparacion onda "is not in " con reservas ( siempre van a estar con clave pri asi que null o not null estaría de mas  )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casi lo tenías. Prueba así:

```
SELECT
   v.N_Matricula  AS 'Matricula',v.Año_ITV AS 'Año de ITV'
FROM 
    vehiculos v 
WHERE 
  (v.fk_IdCategoria=(
    SELECT categoria.IdCategoria
    FROM categoria
    WHERE categoria.Nombre='deportivo')
  ) AND 
  (v.IdVehiculo NOT IN(
    SELECT DISTINCT reservas.IdVehiculo_reservado
    FROM reservas
    )
  );
```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios para poder completar la respuesta como mejor se adapte a tu duda.